# Word Content Controls -> What do the arrows at the side of a content control mean?

Tags: xml, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I am creating a word document with plain text content controls.

I have added a few of these and got code working that substitutes value from an XML file into the content controls. However now when i add a content control to the template I can see whats like a play sign before and after the tag text when in design mode( <| and |> ). Can someone explain what these are and how to get rid of them as they are causing my code to crash.
This line returns null when the symbols are on the content control tags

```
XElement run = element.Element(w + "sdtContent").Element(w + "r");
```

It returns a value for all the other tags.

Comment: Do they look like http://kintespace.com/bitmaps/blog_word2010_content_controls.jpg ?  If so, that is normal and your code is likely at fault.  If not, please post a screen shot.

Comment: Yeah thats them. What do they signify? My code works for tags where they are not there. I have worked around the issue by copying and pasting the working tags and replacing the text, but I would like a better understanding of what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sign appears when sdtContent contains a Paragraph as displayed below

```
<w:sdt>
  <w:sdtPr>        
    <w:id w:val="397949701"/>
    <w:placeholder>
      <w:docPart w:val="6FCFBA48E30F4D3797F7E20820FF13DE"/>
    </w:placeholder>
    <w:showingPlcHdr/>
    <w:text/>
  </w:sdtPr>
  <w:sdtEndPr/>
  <w:sdtContent>
    <w:p w:rsidR="008D0325" w:rsidRPr="008D0325" w:rsidRDefault="008D0325" w:rsidP="008D0325">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:b/>
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r w:rsidR="00060F2E" w:rsidRPr="004E36F4">
        <w:t>Click here to enter text.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:sdtContent>
</w:sdt>
```